# What is the lodash equivalent for a reverse for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, lodash

I'm trying to figure out how to recreate this type of reverse for loop in lodash:

Here the last item of the Array will be iterated on first:

`for (var j=quotes.data[data_location].length-1; j>=0; j--)`

For the regular for loop:

`for (var j=0; j < quotes.data[data_location].length; j++)`

I can accomplish this with lodash's **[_.each](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach)**:

`_.each(quotes.data[data_location], function(quote) {`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lodash has [`forEachRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs#forEachRight).

---

Without lodash, you could call [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) on the loop first, which will mutate the original array. If you don't want to do this, you can create a shallow copy of the array with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Keep in mind that this will essentially add another iteration in your code. If this is performance critical, a backwards counting `for` loop is a good idea.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this mutates the original array, as well.

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah `forEachRight` was what I was looking for :) Thanks! lodash is so much better to read / reason about...

Comment: Its shorter alias is `_.eachRight`.